# RShiny: checkboxInput numeric conversion not working in scoring methodology

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny, scoring

I'm wanting to use checkboxInput to indicate which variables need to go into a scoring methodology (i.e., have the ability to leave some variables out if desired). I want the checkboxInput to be converted to a 0 or 1, and this number will be used in a scoring algorithm.

I know the scoring methodology is working because it will work when I have default variables chosen which ignore the checkboxInput, but not with these manual check boxes.

I'd greatly appreciate any help. Below isn't an exact replica of code; just a simplified version to make this easier for readers. If this way too simplified, let me know; the actual code is pretty complicated but I want to highlight the simple issue that's causing me such a headache for an unknown reason. Thank you!

I've tried making the checkboxInput a reactive variable(s), I've turned them into integers, etc. I feel like there's something obvious I'm missing.

Here is the code:

ui:

```
    (
        uiOutput('variable1selected'),  
        uiOutput('variable2selected'), 
        uiOutput("variable3selected")
    )
```

server:

```
    output$variable1selected = renderUI({
        checkboxInput("variable1selected",
            "Include Variable 1 in Analysis",
             value=TRUE)
    })
    output$variable2selected = renderUI({
        checkboxInput("variable2selected",
            "Include Variable 2 in Analysis",
            value=TRUE)
    })
    output$variable3selected = renderUI({
        checkboxInput("variable3selected",
        "Include Variable 3 in Analysis",
        value=TRUE)
    })

    variable1selected = as.integer(input$variable1selected)
    variable2selected = as.integer(input$variable2selected)
    variable3selected = as.integer(input$variable3selected)

    Score = variable1selected*10 + variable2selected*20 + 
        variable3selected*30
```

There aren't any error messages, it's just not scoring at all when the checkboxInput is selected. I'm expecting a score for each row, and then I sort the table by that score. What's actually being produced is an unsorted table because there is no score present to sort (the "Score" variable is NA for each row).

Comment: Doesn't score have to be calculated inside a reactive context?

Comment: Hi @cory, thank you for taking a look. The checkboxInput used to be a numericInput where I'd enter in values for variables manually (0 or 1). I'd then throw those numbers into the scoring method, similar to above. I didn't need a reactive expression for that score. The reactive expressions here are my latest in a string of attempts to solve the issue. I'll try making the score reactive, but other than that does it look like anything needs to be changed? Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reactive()` function is going to be your best friend with this. You were almost there with what you were wanting to do:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput('variable1selected'),  
    uiOutput('variable2selected'), 
    uiOutput("variable3selected"),
    uiOutput("Score")
)

server <- function(input,output){
    output$variable1selected = renderUI({
        checkboxInput("variable1selected",
                      "Include Variable 1 in Analysis",
                      value=TRUE)
    })
    output$variable2selected = renderUI({
        checkboxInput("variable2selected",
                      "Include Variable 2 in Analysis",
                      value=TRUE)
    })
    output$variable3selected = renderUI({
        checkboxInput("variable3selected",
                      "Include Variable 3 in Analysis",
                      value=TRUE)
    })

    variable1selected = reactive({as.integer(input$variable1selected)})
    variable2selected = reactive({as.integer(input$variable2selected)})
    variable3selected = reactive({as.integer(input$variable3selected)})

    Score = reactive({variable1selected()*10 + variable2selected()*20 + 
        variable3selected()*30})

    output$Score <- renderText(Score())
}



# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to type that. For reasons that may be very long-winded to explain, I want to avoid making the Score reactive because the checkboxInput is only used in a certain circumstance - otherwise the 1 or 0 is predetermined. I've edited my code to look more like how it looked when I used numericInput instead of checkboxInput (but have included checkboxInput since that's what I'm using now). Given how it looks now, do you see any obvious errors? Thanks so much again!

Comment: You would still want it to be `Reactive()` you just need to have an if statement for the predetermined circumstances.

Comment: Thank you - it was something else which was causing all checkboxInput options to be NA. Thank you so much for the help though! I appreciate it tremendously.